# REST calls across site collections?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Having trouble finding a clear answer on this but can I do REST calls to a library across Site Collections within the same domain?

So if I have `mysite.com/r/Site1` and `mysite.com/r/Site2`

Given permissions on `Site 1` are set to everyone in the AD can read.
Will I be able from `Site 2` to return documents from a list in `Site 1` using the REST API?

I know I can use the `Search API` but I'm curious about REST

Comment: You asked 2 hours ago.. you could have found the answer yourself with a quick try. Yes, if the user can access a SiteCollection then the user can call any endpoints in that SC

Comment: I'm not in an environment where I have access to create site collections so I couldn't thanks. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You don't have to create site collections to test... You could've simply opened IE/Chrome dev tools and did a quick test and had an answer in less than five minutes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the both Site Collections are under the same hostname (for example https://my.site.com for both of them), and if the user has the correct permissions, then yes you can use REST.

Answer (score 0):

Call below function in site1.

siteUrl is url of your second site
listName is name of list from which you want to get detail.

```
function getListItem(siteUrl, listName) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",            
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```